# ReCharts: Donut Chart w/two labels in center

Tags: reactjs, donut-chart, recharts

I have a donut chart in which i need to add two stacked labels in center which I have done. What i can't figure out is how to add a little vertical space between.  ReCharts renders both these lines as SVG The chart is in a responsive container so no hard coded values. I know how to get a single label in center but can't figure out how to get two separate ones there without writing a render method for the entire chart. Suggestions?

```
<ResponsiveContainer>
            <PieChart >
              <Tooltip/>
              <Legend
                verticalAlign="bottom"
                align="left"
                iconType="circle"
                payload={ getCustomLegendValues(tasks) } />
              <Pie
                data={tasks}
                nameKey="name"
                dataKey="value"
                innerRadius="60%"
                outerRadius="80%"
                startAngle={90}
                endAngle={-270}
                fill="#8884d8">
                {
                  tasks.map((entry, index) => <Cell fill={ entry.color }/>)
                }
                <Label width={30} position="center">
                  { `${totalTasks} ${tasksNameLabel}` }
                </Label>
              </Pie>
            </PieChart>
          </ResponsiveContainer>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [content property of the Label](http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/Label) component in order to create your own custom Label because both the children and the value property only accept string or numbers. With the content property you can pass a component as such:

```
<Label width={30} position="center"
  content={<CustomLabel value1={totalTasks} value2={tasksNameLabel}/>}>
</Label>
```

and the CustomLabel component:

```
function CustomLabel({viewBox, value1, value2}){
  const {cx, cy} = viewBox;
  return (
   <text x={cx} y={cy} fill="#3d405c" className="recharts-text recharts-label" textAnchor="middle" dominantBaseline="central">
      <tspan alignmentBaseline="middle" fontSize="26">{value1}</tspan>
      <tspan fontSize="14">{value2}</tspan>
   </text>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is this working ? i have tried but the label not rendering

Comment: @SoorajJose this renders both values in one line and not one under another.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but I recently played with this and looks like you can use multiple Label components and tweak their positions with css. Here is what I tweaked from the Recharts example:

```
const {PieChart, Pie, Legend, Tooltip, Cell, Label} = Recharts;
const COLORS = ['#0088FE', '#00C49F', '#FFBB28', '#FF8042'];

const data01 = [{name: 'Group A', value: 5}, {name: 'Group B', value: 4},
                 {name: 'Group C', value: 1}, {name: 'Group D', value: 1}]

const TwoSimplePieChart = React.createClass({
   render () {
   return (
       <PieChart width={800} height={400}>
       <Pie 
       data={data01} 
       cx={300}
       cy={150} 
       innerRadius={60}
       outerRadius={70} 
       fill="#8884d8"
       paddingAngle={2}
       >
       <Label 
       value="6" position="centerBottom"  className='label-top' fontSize='27px'
       />
       <Label 
       value="tasks left" position="centerTop" className='label'
       />
         {
           data01.map((entry, index) => <Cell fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]}/>)
         }
       </Pie>
       <Tooltip/>
      </PieChart>
   );
 }
})

ReactDOM.render(
 <TwoSimplePieChart />,
 document.getElementById('container')
);
```

and CSS:

```
.label-top {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

You can check the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/trung2012/pcbq3146/34/

Comment: This is works just fine! I was wondering if there a was to wrap the label text. That would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the labels one above another. I made the below change to accomplish it.

```
<Label width={30} position="center"
  content={<CustomLabel value1={totalTasks} value2={tasksNameLabel}/>}>
</Label>
```

And the Custom labels will be as follows:

```
function CustomLabel(props) {
  const { cx, cy } = props.viewBox;
  return (
    <>
      <text
        x={cx}
        y={cy - 5}
        fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)"
        className="recharts-text recharts-label"
        textAnchor="middle"
        dominantBaseline="central"
      >
        <tspan alignmentBaseline="middle" fontSize="31.5px" fontFamily="Roboto">
          {props.value2}
        </tspan>
      </text>
      <text
        x={cx}
        y={cy + 20}
        fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)"
        className="recharts-text recharts-label"
        textAnchor="middle"
        dominantBaseline="central"
      >
        <tspan fontSize="12.3px" fontFamily="Roboto">
          {props.value1}
        </tspan>
      </text>
    </>
  );
}
```